# RxJava introduced Single<T>. How do I convert an Observable<T> to a Single<T>?

Tags: rx-java, observable

RxJava recently introduced [Single](http://reactivex.io/documentation/single.html). Is there a way to convert an already existing Observable (that's pretty much a Single) to a Single without modifying the source of the original observable?

For example, I have an api service class with a method that returns an Observable - which is essentially fetching a User from a remote resource. Say I can't modify the service. I want to consume this elsewhere but return a Single. How do I do this?

**A pinch more background**

RxJava recently introduced the concept of a Single which is more or less an Rx friendly simple callback (i.e. an Observable emitting one object or an error) (read more about it here - http://reactivex.io/documentation/single.html)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I think another answer is outdated. You should probably check the following methods.

**singleOrError:** Emits the one and only element, IndexOutOfBoundsException if the source is longer than 1 item or a NoSuchElementException if the source is empty.

**firstOrError:** Emits the first element or a NoSuchElementException if the source is empty.

**lastOrError:** Emits the lastelement or a NoSuchElementException if the source is empty.

**elementAtOrError:** Emits the indexth element or a NoSuchElementException.

More info on this page: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What%27s-different-in-2.0

Answer (score 34):

#### Note: This is for RxJava 1. See other answers below/above for Rx2 :)

---

2 new convenience methods were added to accomplish this very thing.

`toSingle()` converts an Observable that emits a single item into a Single that emits that item

`toObservable` converts a Single into an Observable that emits the item emitted by the Single and then completes

(source: http://reactivex.io/documentation/single.html)

Comment: note that if single has no items, .toObservable() will not make it return Observable.empty(). Instead it will still throw NoSuchElementException. So resulting observable is not the same thing as if the source were an Observable to begin with.

Answer (score 26):

In **rxjava2** you can use `Single.fromObservable()`.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-android/blob/main/apollo-rx2-support/src/main/java/com/apollographql/apollo/rx2/RxJavaExtensions.kt

There is an extension for ApolloClient.

`rxQuery` gives you Observable<Response>
`rxMutate` gives you Single<Response>

and see others.